# ReactJS : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error that only occurs temporarily

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a bit of a weird issue with a React project I've been working on. It is a basic Maths Game where users have to enter and submit their answer.

Most of the time, the game works as intended, but sometimes the game won't progress and I see a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

in the console. Investigating this, it points to the line in my JS that reads:

```
"let correctAnswer = eval(`${num1} ${sign} ${num2}`);"
```

I cannot see anything immediately wrong with this line and I've tried stepping through the functions involved to try and catch anything suspicious, but no luck.

I know this kind of error usually points towards a typo, but I haven't noticed any missing semicolons or brackets. Furthermore, after clicking a few times, I can get the game running again as normal.

How can a Uncaught SyntaxError be temporary?

I will post my code here, but with the Codepen linked you can see the behaviour I'm talking about. 
Codepen: https://codepen.io/augs0/pen/MWwXGNd?editors=0010

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      name: undefined,
      num1: undefined,
      sign: undefined,
      num2: undefined,
      isWrong: false,
      correctAnswer: undefined,
      answer: undefined,
      score: 0,
      user: undefined
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState(() => {
        this.createQuestion();
      });
    };

    updateName = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
      });
    };

    startGame = (e) => {
      const { name, score } = this.state;
      // deal with blank entry
      if (!name) return;

      //create object for new user to access this info for the current player
      const newUser = {
        score: 0,
        name
      };

      this.setState({
        user: newUser
      });
    };

    getAnswer = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        // what does this plus actually do?
        answer: +e.target.value
      });
    };

    clearField = () => {
      document.getElementById('form').reset();
    }

    checkAnswer = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { correctAnswer, answer, score } = this.state;
      let newScore = undefined;
      if (correctAnswer === answer) {
        newScore = score + 1;
        this.clearField();
        this.createQuestion();
        this.setState({
          score: newScore,
          isWrong: false
        });
      } else {
        console.log(correctAnswer);
        newScore = score - 1;
        this.setState({
          score: newScore,
          isWrong: true
        });
      }
    };

    getRandomNumber = (size = 1) => {
      const minNr = 1;
      // Fill replaces the data in the array
      const maxNr = +Array(size).fill(9).join("");
      // +1 allows us to reach beyond 10 with Math.random
      const nr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNr - minNr + 1) + minNr);
      return nr;
    };

    getRandomSign = () => {
      const signs = ["x", "*", "/", "+"];
      const randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * signs.length);

      return signs[randomizer];
    };

    createQuestion = (size = 1) => {
      const num1 = this.getRandomNumber(size);
      const sign = this.getRandomSign();
      const num2 = this.getRandomNumber(size);
      let correctAnswer = eval(`${num1} ${sign} ${num2}`);

      if (
        Math.floor(correctAnswer) !== correctAnswer ||
        correctAnswer === Infinity //prevent questions where the answer is a decimal or infinity
      ) {
        return this.createQuestion(size);
        // correctAnswer = Number(correctAnswer.toFixed(1)); 
      } else {
        this.setState({
          num1,
          sign,
          num2,
          correctAnswer
        });
        // this.checkScore()
      }
    };

    // checkScore = () => {
    //   const {name, score} = this.state;
    //   if(`${score} < 25`){
    //     console.log('Not yet!')
    //   }
    // }

    render() {
      const { name, num1, sign, num2, isWrong, score, user } = this.state;
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Maths game with React</h1>
          {user ? (
            <div>
              <h2>Hello, {name}</h2>
              <h2>Score: {score}</h2>
              <form id='form' onSubmit={this.checkAnswer}>
              <h2>Question:</h2>
              <div className="question">
                <p>{num1}</p>
                <p>{sign}</p>
                <p>{num2}</p>
                <p> = </p>
                <input
                  className={`answer ${isWrong && "wrong"}`}
                  type="number"
                  onChange={this.getAnswer}
                />
                <button onClick={this.checkAnswer}>Check answer</button>
              </div>
              </form>
              <div className="leaderboard">
                <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
                <p className="number-one">#1 The Maths Menace</p>
                <p className="score-one">100</p>
                <p className="number-two">#2 The Mean Average</p>
                <p className="score-two">50</p>
                <p className="number-three">#3 Here For Pi</p>{" "}
                <p className="score-three">25</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <p>
                Welcome to the Maths Game! Here you can practice your maths skills
                while trying to beat the high score.
              </p>
              <p>Please enter a username then click 'Start' to begin.</p>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.updateName} />
              <button className="btn" onClick={this.startGame}>
                Start
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: You are calling a setState in a setState via createQuestion without returning a value in the first setState? This is bound to get ugly.

Comment: what is the perpose of undefined :( `name: undefined` default is undefined

Comment: @xdeepakv this is probably just unnecessary code on my part, apologies for the confusion

Comment: @Gh05d I'm still learning React so it's not perfect. I would suggest that you don't just use commenting as an opportunity to take a passing swipe at somebody without much more to the comment. Thank you for commenting in any case. It's something I'll look into.

Comment: I was just shocked by the code. Did not mean any insult to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem occurs when "x" is selected from this array as `x` is not a valid arithmetic operator, but `*`, `/` and `+` are:

`getRandomSign = () => { const signs = ["x", "*", "/", "+"];`

I'm assuming that it was supposed to be a minus operator, in which case swapping it for a hyphen `-` should do the trick.

Example of when the error occurs:

[image: Screenshot of code being evaluated in Chrome Dev Tools]

---

Bonus:

`// what does this plus actually do? answer: +e.target.value`

I'm guessing the `+` operator is being used to cast the value to an integer. I've done a similar trick in the past but by adding `- 0` to the end of a string.

Comment: Thank you! This did indeed solve the issue. Answer accepted.

Comment: you beat me to it:
i added:
console.log(\`${num1} ${sign} ${num2}\`) 
just before the error line: let correctAnswer = eval(\`${num1} ${sign} ${num2}\`); and saw the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Ether one of these coming undefined:

```
let correctAnswer = eval(`${num1} ${sign} ${num2}`);
```

change it to

```
let correctAnswer = `${num1} ${sign} ${num2}`

eval(`${undefined} ${undefined} ${undefined}`) //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```